# Query using starts with

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

A little help to do the following:

I am good with Queries however, can't find if it is possible to do the following:

`=Query(range, "Select * where B begins with (**want a range from A to Can**)` to query by last names within  the letters A to Can.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following as your "Select" clause:

`"Select * Where UPPER(B) >= 'A' AND UPPER(B) < 'CANZ'"`

I followed `CAN` with `Z` so that all words beginning with `CAN` would be selected (e.g., "Canada," "canopy," etc.).
I could have entered `CAO` to get the same results here, since every word beginning with `CAN...` will fall before `CAO` alphabetically.

The gist here is that, because **all alphanumeric characters exist on the ASCII chart, they can be compared as equal, greater-than or less-than just like true numbers**.

Comment: Excellent solution. Kudos Erik :)

Comment: Thanks, @marikamitsos.